# Can we use spring-boot external config file name with dash `-` or underscore `_`?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to running `springboot-2.x` fat jar in window by using external configuration.

I have three different external config file like:

```
C:\application-myconfig.yml
C:\application_myconfig.yml
C:\applicationmyconfig.yml
```

the configuration is :

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /application1

mymessage: this is test message
```

In my window, I run the following commend to run `spring-boot` fat jar.

Option-1

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:\\\C:/application-myconfig.yml aplication1.jar
```

Option-2

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:\\\C:/application_myconfig.yml aplication1.jar
```

Option-3

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:\\\C:/applicationmyconfig.yml aplication1.jar
```

The strange thing is `Option-1` and `Option-2` does not work. It is cannot find/load config file.

Only `Option-3` is work for me.

My question is **Can we use `spring-boot` config file name with dash `-` or underscore `_`?**

Comment: You can use config file with '-' (dash) and with '_' (underscore). As long as file names are correct, you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to naming convention, you can use hyphen (-) in case of both yml and properties file for spring boot application, you can refer below the spring documentation. Refer to the section

> 24.7.4 YAML Shortcomings

Regarding naming convention of names in yml file, refer to the table

> Table 24.1. relaxed binding

Link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Also refer below, spring says to quote

**If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (for example, SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of spring.config.name)**